# EF, How to save and entity to DB without saving its navigation property?

Tags: entity-framework

I have a MessageRecipient object that have a User as navigation property. When I add a MessageRecipient to DB it also tries to add the User which is not what i want doing. Is there any way to somehow remove the User from MessageRecipient or just prevent EF from saving navigation properties? I do not want to add or update the associated User object. Thanks

```
        entity.MessageRecipients.Add(recipient);
        entity.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are trying to add a MessageRecipient to a User correct?  If this is the case you need to get the User from the Database (or attach to current context) then add the Message Recipient to the User then SaveChanges.  Doing so will not create new User but actually add child data to that Object/Database.

Comment: what i"m trying to do is to add a MessageRecipient to a DB. The User is a navigation property that has been populated when i needed it to display the users details. Now when i add the MessageRecipient to a DB it also tries to update the User which i do not want to do at all.

Comment: So if you make changes to the User, via your new MessageRecipient, you do not want those User changes to persist to the database?  Only the new MessageRecipient?  I think I'm missing a settle detail here.

Comment: Yes thats correct :) sorry my english could be a lot better and sometimes i have difficulties expressing what i exactly mean.

Comment: @Pawel, no worries.  English is my native language and I too have moments. :)  Sorry, I went on vacation and couldn't help.  Shall we figure this out still?  We'll have to investigate Change Tracking for that object because the User object is attached (hence the updates).  You'll want that to be set to "Unchanged" (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896269.aspx).